# iPhone:Effects for recorded video?

Tags: iphone

I have a program to allow user to record the video. I have to provide options like Black&White, Crystal etc. like how "Viddy" iPhone application does for setting more Effects to the recorded video. How can i achieve it programmatically?

Please guide me.

Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

Here's one way:

1. Start capturing video frames with AVCaptureSession+AVCaptureVideoDataOutput
2. Convert the frames to OpenGL textures for display
3. Write GLSL shaders for each desired effect and apply to textures from step 2
4. Read back textures + effect and write to movie file
5. Optimise until performance is adequate
6. goto 5

5 is probably the most important step. You'll need to tune and tweak the algorithm, video quality, texture size, frame rates, shaders, etc.

Enjoy!

Comment: My application is not an OpenGL application.

Comment: I don't think you can avoid OpenGL here.

Comment: In step 4 - how would you go about reading back the textures and saving to a file? UIImage? something else?

Comment: either glReadPixels > CGBitmapContext > CGImage > UIImage > UIImagePNGRepresentation or RenderToTexture on CVOpenGLESTextureCache managed CVPixelBuffer and then CGBitmapContext, etc, etc, etc. Seems awfully long though, I'm sure you could find a simpler solution with less copying. p.s. this should probably be a new question.